# javascript - how is functionality Hook order of execution works?

Tags: javascript

I don't know how to ask this on google that's why I asked here instead,
The `console.log` from the `getListByElement()` function won't execute here, 
I am modifying a very large existing project and uses functionality hooks for validation purposes and executes that hook on certain .on events, what I want to know is why the console.log won't get executed,
which gets executed first,

```
Order of execution on my understanding
1. trigger event function for the field `fieldName`
2. fieldName.functionalityHook = [Apple.functionalityHook()];
3. Apple.functionalityHook = function(func) {
4. return function(e) {
5. getListByElement(ele); and display console.log();
6. return func;
```

Here is the sample code that I have,

```
var Apple= window.Apple; // global

fieldName.functionalityHook = [Apple.functionalityHook()];

Apple.functionalityHook = function(func) {

        return function(e) {

            var ele = $(e.target);

            getListByElement(ele);

            return func;
        }
}

function getListByElement(ele){
    console.log('ele here');
}
```

Thank You for answering,

Comment: Since we don't know how `fieldName.functionalityHook` is invoked, we can't tell you why the function is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

as par my understanding your getListByElement() is not invoking because of the function initialization. You are calling the functionalityHook() before its initialization.

```
fieldName.functionalityHook = [Apple.functionalityHook()];

Apple.functionalityHook = function(func) {..........
```

and this invocation returning a function

```
return function(e) {

        var ele = $(e.target);

        getListByElement(ele);

        return func;
    }
```

and inside this function getListByElement() is calling.

So, the correct code arrangement should be like this.

```
var Apple= window.Apple;

function getListByElement(ele){
    console.log('ele here');
}

Apple.functionalityHook = function(func) {

    return function(e) {

        var ele = $(e.target);

        getListByElement(ele);

        return func;
    }
}

fieldName.functionalityHook = [Apple.functionalityHook()];
```

Comment: Good catch! Should be obvious if the OP looked at their browser's console.